# How add value to arraylist from a constructor?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

How add value to arraylist which is in constructor of another class
Employee.java

```
public Employee(String name, String job, int age, String email, ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers)
{}
```

Dataentry.java

```
public List<Employee> createListEmployees(){
List<Employee> retVal = new ArrayList();
Employee( String name, String job, int age, String email, ArrayList<String> 
phoneNumbers);
retVal.add(new Employee("Bob", "Technician", 33, "bob@bobemail.com",
("555123123","5553213213")));
retVal.add(new Employee("Jane", "Accountant", 33, "jane@mail.com", 
["525123123","5553413213"]));
```

Comment: Should be `new ArrayList<Employee>()` or `new ArrayList<>()`.  However, you haven't actually asked a specific question.  You gave us some code, but you didn't tell us anything about it.  Does it give an error?  Does it throw an exception?  If so, tell us what the error or exception is and where it's occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly construct the `ArrayList` for the phone numbers:

```
List<Employee> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
retVal.add(new Employee("Bob", "Technician", 33, "bob@bobemail.com",
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("555123123","5553213213"))));
```

If you would change your constructor signature to use the `List` interface type, things become a little simpler:

```
public Employee(String name, String job, int age, String email,
        List<String> phoneNumbers) {

    /* ... */
}

List<Employee> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
retVal.add(new Employee("Bob", "Technician", 33, "bob@bobemail.com",
        Arrays.asList("555123123","5553213213")));
```